# Is necessary purchase some physical devices (smartphone/tablets) for develop/test a mobile website?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm currently developing a mobile website with jquery mobile, not exactly responsive web design. I know I can develop the project in the browser on my desktop PC with some plugins or use some online services or simulators available. But I'm not sure if I missing something really important for test.

Example:

> touch/swype events or viewport rotation.

Is necessary purchase some physical devices (smartphone/tablets) to develop/test the project? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Intro

First don't let anyone tell you it is not necessary to purchase a real devices for a test purpose. I will tell you why from an Android perspective, same thing, just in a much smaller manner also goes for iOS development.

## Good sides of an emulator testing

- It is free, you only need a computer which will run your emulator.
- You can test your applications in different cases (different screen resolutions, different OS versions)
- Faster I/O and network operations but this is not so much a good point if you calculate how much everything else is slow.

## Bad sides

- It is slooooooooow, if you never tried to use it you can comprehend how slow it is (iOS emulator is fast like hell in a comparison). It doesn't matter if you have a top of a line hardware PC or Mac it is just that slow.
- Emulator is simply to darn buggy, there will be a lot of times when application will work just fine on a read device and it will brake on an emulator.
- This also goes other way around, sometimes application will work just fine on an emulator but will brake on a real device, in some case it will not work at all or it will not work on some devices. This is usually a case when working with hybrid applications. for some reason Android web view acts differently on real devices and on an emulator.
- Emulator simply don't have some functionalities to interact with a hardware nor it can successfully emulate it. Hardware connection it can emulate even don't work correctly sometimes.
- I have talked about how slow it is (because of a converting ARM bytecodes to x86 ones on the fly) but from a graphics standpoint it tends to be even slower so don't expect to do any game development on it.
- Real devices comes with much more preinstalled software which may slower your application or in some ways enhance its functionalities.
- Real world GPS testing is out of a question

## Final notes

If you are intending to work with iOS only emulator can be used to do much of a development. Sheer lack of different screens sizes and hardware diversity makes it a perfect platform for a test purposes. Android on the other hand is completely different story, its emulator is simply useless for test purposes. I have several real Android devices, ranging from Android 2.1 + , different screen sizes and finally hardware architecture. You don't need to believe me but everything I mentioned play a significant role while testing Android applications.

If your main concern is testing your jQuery Mobile application I would still advise you a use of a real device in case of Android while in case of iOS you can successfully use emulator. Android is problematic because transition effects are to darn slow and that includes everything else that requires animations. Swipe will not be a problem and I can vouch it works just fine. Second real problem is a device rotation. jQuery Mobile sometimes can have a problem with it, mostly when used with non responsive 3rd party jQuery plugins (carousels, sliders ....). Third problem is mentioned in my list of bad sides, basically web view used in a emulator acts different then one in a real phone so sometimes you will see one thing in your real device and one thing in your emulator.

Comment: While alot of what you are saying is true for apps, that are installed, the asker specifically requested advice on testing mobile websites. But still, +1 for extensive and comprehensive answer that is otherwise correct.

Comment: Tnx for your comment, I just got distracted by this topic, android emulators are thorn in my side ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to purchase such a device.

For Android there is an emulator provided by the Android Development Kit (ADK). You can use it to configure multiple emulated devices with defferent screen sizes, etc. to test for multiple resolutions and Android (browser) versions.

[edit] Though to really test it for iphones you would need that emulator too I suppose, to make sure the website is correctly displayed in the provided browser.

[edit 2] To test "real" smartphone apps (not webapps), it is better to have a real device at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This very much depends to which level you want to test it before you are happy to hand it over for the usage. After you do that and someone reports a defect, will you be able to see where is the problem (if it works on your PC)?

The development itself can be done in your browser, you can even simluate swipe events by dragging mouse. You don't even need any simulators, you can just make chrome window smaller (most of the devices are using some version of webkit, same as chrome).

However, once it comes to testing, I wouldn't feel great if I didn't know how it looks on the device itself. So I think having at least one device (ideally two with different OS and resolution) is always beneficial.

I would also be unsatisfied if I was working on something of which I could not see the result :)